# Using the replace operator on a string that has quotes powershell

Tags: powershell, quotes

I am looking to run the command

```
foreach-object {$_ -replace
```

However the string I am attempting to work with could be described as the follow

```
this string "has" quotes
```

the whole line being

```
foreach-object {$_ -replace "this string "has" quotes", "this string "won't have" quotes"}
```

How do I make this quote filled line work with powershell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either escape the nested double quotes like so `` `" `` or better yet, use single quotes for quoting of the string then you won't need to escape the double quotes e.g.:

```
'this string "has" quotes'
```

Note: with single quotes you won't get variable expansion in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can Grave (the tilde key) double quotation marks as an escape character. You can do this to any special character in a string.

e.g.

```
$a = "This String `"Has`" Quotes"
$a = $a.replace("This String `"Has`" Quotes","this string won't have quotes. ")
```