# insert fails in psql.exe (created from powershell)

Tags: sql, postgresql, powershell

I am creating "dynamic" sql statements from Powershell and pass it to PostGreSQL server on Windows.

Below is the code

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 9; $i++)
{
$CurDate = (get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
$BatchLogInsert = "Insert into `"TEMP`".`"batchLog`" (batchid, filename, status, createdate) values ('" + $NewBatchID + "','File"+$i+"','Init','"+$CurDate+"');"
write-host $BatchLogInsert

C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe -h $DBSERVER -U $DBUSER -d $CLIENTPREFIX -w -c $BatchLogInsert
}
```

write-host returns:

```
Insert into "TEMP"."batchLog" (batchid, filename, status, createdate) values ('3','File1','Init','2014-01-13 16:24:49');
Insert into "TEMP"."batchLog" (batchid, filename, status, createdate) values ('3','File2','Init','2014-01-13 16:24:49');
Insert into "TEMP"."batchLog" (batchid, filename, status, createdate) values ('3','File3','Init','2014-01-13 16:24:49');
```

and so on.

When I execute these inserts in the "Query" window of PGAdmin, it works. However, when I am calling the psql.exe, it fails saying

```
ERROR: Relation "TEMP.batchLog" does not exist
LINE 1: Insert into TEMP.batchLog (batchid, filename, status, created...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of my powershell window and PgAdmin window...
[image: Screenshot]

---

Comment: Either you're not executing the same queries in `psql` and pgAdmin, or (more probably) you're not connecting to the same database.

Comment: `"TEMP.batchLog" ` is different from `"TEMP"."batchLog"` (probably your pgadmin submit did not include any quotes at all)

Comment: @MilenA.Radev I know it seems wrong, but, dont know what will be a good way to show I am trying to connect to the correct DB. Its my first time with PostGreSql and I am having trouble with what seems to get a simple insert work correctly

Comment: @wildplasser As above, I believe, I have run the output from Powershell (write-host) to the PgAdmin, and it is working correctly. However, this beats me on what is taking such a trivial thing to get accomplished.

Comment: Escaping the double quotes with backslash _and_ backtick works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your double quotes are eaten by Powershell, Postgres sees an unquoted table name, folds it to lowercase and fails to find such a table.

Proper double quotes escaping seems to involve backslashes **and** backticks:

```
$BatchLogInsert = "Insert into \`"TEMP\`".\`"batchLog\`" (...
```

It would be easier to avoid using different case in DB object names altogether.

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks.

`'Insert into \"'+$Schema+'\".\"batchLog\" (batchid, filename, st`...

Answer (score 0):

Any time you're doing "string building," I recommend that people use .NET string formatting in PowerShell. Furthermore, using the `Start-Process` cmdlet can make passing arguments to executables a lot easier.

```
$PSql = 'C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe';

for ($i=1; $i -le 9; $i++)
{
    $CurDate = (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    $BatchLogInsert = 'Insert into "TEMP"."batchLog" (batchid, filename, status, createdate) values (''{0}'', ''File{1}'', ''Init'', ''{2}'');' -f $NewBatchID, $i, $CurDate;
    Write-Host -Object $BatchLogInsert;

    $ArgumentList = '-h {0} -U {1} -d {2} -w -c "{3}"' -f $DBServer, $DBUser, $ClientPrefix, $BatchLogInsert;
    Start-Process -FilePath $PSql -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Wait -NoNewWindow;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this will work, because every object (Table, view, colone...etc) which name contains a upper-case must be wrote quoted. You have to modify the generation of insert instruction.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan: Thanks. But, I still ended up getting the same error. 

`Insert into "TEMP"."batchLog" (batchid, filename, status, createdate) values ('4', 'File1', 'Init', '2014-01-14 08:47:26'
);
ERROR:  relation "temp.batchlog" does not exist
LINE 1: Insert into TEMP.batchLog (batchid, filename, status, created...`

Comment: @Houari Can you please share an example? our company has recently (and abruptly) decided to switch to PostGreSQL from SQLServer. We are trying to learn it as we try to modify our previous scripts which catered to SQLServer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either escape the nested double quotes like so `" or better yet, use single quotes for quoting of the string then you won't need to escape the double quotes. Try replace:

```
 $BatchLogInsert = 'Insert into "TEMP"."batchLog" (batchid, filename, status, createdate) values (''{0}'', ''File{1}'', ''Init'', ''{2}'');' -f $NewBatchID, $i, $CurDate;
```

With

```
$BatchLogInsert = 'Insert into ""TEMP"".""batchLog"" (batchid, filename, status, createdate) values (''' + $NewBatchID + ''',''File'+$i.ToSTring()+''',''Init'','''+$CurDate+''');';
```

Based on: [Response]:https://stackoverflow.com/a/11192247/1216680