# How to do search & replace in mingw with quotes in the string?

Tags: bash, powershell, sed, mingw

Using `sed` in mingw but it corrupts the security settings, powershell works, for example:

```
powershell -Command "(gc configure) -replace 'uname -msr', 'uname -ms' | Out-File -encoding ASCII configure"
```

However, this doesn't work when I need to have quotes in the find/replace strings. How can I escape the quotes in that powershell command and / or find & replace in general without corrupting the files?

I've tried `` `" `` but then the quote trips bash up. I've tried `` `\" `` but that didn't work either.

My question is not a duplicate of [Using the replace operator on a string that has quotes powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192064) because I'm dealing with both powershell and bash here.

Here are examples I've tried without success:

```
$ powershell -Command \"(Get-Content CMakeLists.txt).Replace(\"SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS \"${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /W4\")\", \"SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS \"${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}\\")") | Out-File -encoding ASCII configure\"
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('

$ powershell -Command "(Get-Content CMakeLists.txt).Replace("SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /W4")", "SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")") | Out-File -encoding ASCII configure"
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('

# this one goes through...
$ powershell -Command "(Get-Content CMakeLists.txt).Replace('SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /W4")', 'SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")') | Out-File -encoding ASCII configure"

# But doesn't actually apply the change
$ cat CMakeLists.txt | grep CMAKE_C_FLAGS
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
  SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /W4")
```

[Here is the file](https://github.com/lloyd/yajl/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) I'd like to do replacement on, and these are all the replacements I'd like to do:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /W4") to SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
SET(linkFlags "/PDB:NONE /INCREMENTAL:NO /OPT:NOREF /OPT:NOICF") to SET(linkFlags)
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /wd4996 /wd4255 /wd4130 /wd4100 /wd4711") to SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "/D DEBUG /Od /Z7") to SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "/D NDEBUG /O2") to SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2")
```

Comment: ```\"``` should have worked because the escaping is needed just for bash, not ps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the replace operator on a string that has quotes powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192064/using-the-replace-operator-on-a-string-that-has-quotes-powershell)

Comment: @wOxxOm that's a little misleading as escaping is often required in powershell, it just depends on the situation and how the string is constructed.

Comment: Well, "in this case" was implied.

Comment: @JamesC. it's not a duplicate as I'm dealing with bash here as well, not just powershell.

Comment: can you post the lines from CMakeLists.txt you want to change and the desired result?

Comment: For those of us who are unfamiliar with Powershell, can you explain what the command does? The equivalent `sed -i` script would probably help (probably in conjunction with the explanation of why you can't use `sed -i`).

Comment: sed in mingw corrupts the file permissions or can't replace them to begin with due to file permissions. It was the first thing I tried.

Comment: I don't have access to Powershell but if it wants to receive those quotes, how about adding a layer of single quotes for Bash?  `powershell -Command '\"(Get-Content CMakeLists.txt).Replace(\"SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS \"${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /W4\")\", \"SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS \"${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}\\")") | Out-File -encoding ASCII configure\"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could *avoid using double quotes*  by using the regex `-replace` function for your replacements. This should do it:

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content CMakeLists.txt -Raw) -replace '\/W4' -replace '(?<=SET\(linkFlags)[^\)]+' -replace '\/wd4996 \/wd4255 \/wd4130 \/wd4100 \/wd4711' -replace '(?<=SET\(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG .)\/D \DEBUG \/Od \/Z7', '-g' -replace '(?<=SET\(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE .)\/D NDEBUG \/O2', '-O2' | Out-File -encoding ASCII configure"
```

---

You could also use the `-EncodedCommand` powershell.exe parameter to pass a **base-64-encoded string** version of your command. Here an example how you can get your base-64-encoded string using PowerShell:

```
$cmd = 
@'
(Get-Content CMakeLists.txt).Replace('SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /W4")', 'SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")') | Out-File -encoding ASCII configure
'@

$encodedCmd = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($cmd))
```

Now you can invoke the encoded command using the content of `$encodedCmd` like this:

```
powershell -EncodedCommand 'KABHAGUAdAAtAEMAbwBuAHQAZQBuAHQAIABDAE0AYQBrAGUATABpAHMAdABzAC4AdAB4AHQAKQAuAFIAZQBwAGwAYQBjAGUAKAAnAFMARQBUACgAQwBNAEEASwBFAF8AQwBfAEYATABBAEcAUwAgACIAJAB7AEMATQBBAEsARQBfAEMAXwBGAEwAQQBHAFMAfQAgAC8AVwA0ACIAKQAnACwAIAAnAFMARQBUACgAQwBNAEEASwBFAF8AQwBfAEYATABBAEcAUwAgACIAJAB7AEMATQBBAEsARQBfAEMAXwBGAEwAQQBHAFMAfQAiACkAJwApACAAfAAgAE8AdQB0AC0ARgBpAGwAZQAgAC0AZQBuAGMAbwBkAGkAbgBnACAAQQBTAEMASQBJACAAYwBvAG4AZgBpAGcAdQByAGUA' -NoProfile
```

Comment: I just copied the `Out-File` parameters from your example which will create a new file called `configure` without file extension that contains the replacements. You probably want to change `configure` to `CMakeLists.txt` like: `Out-File -encoding ASCII CMakeLists.txt`

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you can escape characters with the backtick " ` ". Example:

```
$x ="test`""
test"
```

Alternatively you can declare a string with single quotes and use double quotes inside it. Example:

```
$x =  ' "te"st"'
"te"st"
```

Check this [link](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html) for further details.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try use double quote like this

```
powershell -Command "(gc configure).Replace("L'Oréal", "L'Oréal2") | Out-File -encoding ASCII configure"
```

Comment: Didn't work:
<code>
   $ powershell -Command "(Get-Content CMakeLists.txt).Replace("SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /W4")", "SET(CMAKE_C_F
LAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")") | Out-File -encoding ASCII configure"
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('
</code>

Answer (score 0):

You need single quote to wrap your string, and `\` to escape double quote for bash.
This should work

`powershell -Command "(Get-Content CMakeLists.txt).Replace('SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS \"${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /W4\")', 'SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS \"${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}\")') | Out-File -encoding ASCII configure"`

Comment: It has no effect unfortunately: https://hastebin.com/acovosenuv.pl

Is there anything else I could try?